# Passing unknown number of arguments to a function C++ (No CRT)

Tags: c++, arguments, variadic

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to pass an unknown number of variable, similar to ParamArray in .NET

I also need to be able to identify the type of the variables. However, all this without the use of CRT. Now would this be possible?

My goal is to serialize primitive datatypes to a char array.

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: How variadic templates is related to crt ?

Comment: variadic templates are really the only solution here

Comment: @alex How would I go on about retrieving the variable from the T ...?

Edit: And checking its type; whethere it's a char*, int, etc.
I will be operating with pointers.

Comment: @user2079303, Oh sorry, I wrote "no crt", but I think one of the keywords were unavailable to me, my mistake.

Comment: you need to be more specific what exactly are you trying to accomplish with your function?

Comment: Basically, I am serializing primitive data types to a char array. I need to know the data type of the arguments passed, or else I won't know the size and how to treat it.